# How to remove border from card body?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to remove border from bootstrap card body.I have tried lot but couldn't succeed.Here is my code.
https://codepen.io/somen18/pen/VwKVddo

```
            <div class="card h-100">
                    <img src="images/Mask Group.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Prestige High-Cut Leather </h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis,
                            asperiores?.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
                        <h2>$234</h2>
                        <button class="submit"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>BUY NOW</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want like this ?
[Link](https://codepen.io/vantrong291/pen/RwGqmLX)

Just add a CSS border for "card" element.

```
.card {
    border: none !important;
}
```